# Get data day from date when selecting datagridview row

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

i have dgvData(datagridview), cmbPickRoom(combobox), numDay_In & numDay_Out(numericupdown) and code which like this

```
private void dgvData_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvData.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        cmbPickRoom.Text = row.Cells["Room"].Value.ToString();
        numDay_In.Text = row.Cells["Day_In"].Value.ToString();
        numDay_Out.Text = row.Cells["Day_Out"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

while the data in mysql store date format(dd-mm-yyyy) for both "Day_In" and "Day_Out".

I want when i click dgvData, numDay_In and numDay_Out only take the day(dd)

Comment: And what problem do you have with this code?

Comment: i want numDay_In and numDay_Out filled with day value(dd), not date value(dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Are _Day_In_ and _Day_Out_ fields of type DateTime in your MySql table that you have loaded in your DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database fields are of type DateTime, (Day_In and Day_Out) then you don't need to convert these values to string but to a DateTime variable, then getting the day is just a matter of reading a property

```
DateTime inDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Day_In"].Value);
numDay_In.Text = inDate.Day.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.TryParse to convert the user entered string to date time format and then get the Day from it as I have done in the below code.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
if(DateTime.TryParse(row.Cells["Day_In"].Value, out dt))
{
numDay_In.Text = dt.Day.ToString();
}
else
{
//Code to display error message
}
```

The added advantage of this code is that you can check if the user entered format is coorect, by checking the success of the TryParse in an if condition, If it fails, you can prompt the user to enter the Date in the correct format.

Comment: error show up: cannot convert from 'object' to string